# Mysterious nullptr added to std::unordered_map

Tags: c++

I have an unordered map like this:

`std::unordered_map<std::type_index, WidgetMetaData*> m_metaData;`

The `WidgetMetaData` type is not important, the only important thing is that it is a pointer.

Now for some reason, very rarely, a nullptr slips in there. I have no idea where it comes from. **I have added assertions in every single function of the class that contains the unordered map and never does it find a nullptr was added to the map. Ever.**

These assertions look like this:

```
for (const auto& metaPair : m_metaData)
    assert(metaPair.second);
```

**The unordered map is private and never returned as reference.** The only single class that can modify it is the class that contains it.

The nullptr only appears about once every 50 instances, generally around the time I am deleting an instance of that class.

So my question is this: **what could possibly cause a nullptr to appear or replace a healthy pointer without seemingly any code that explicitly tells it to do it?**

Comment: Remember that the `[]` operator creates an entry if one doesn't already exist. Therefore, `if (m_metadata[index]) ...` for a non-existent index will **add it to the map first** (with a nullptr value) and return that nullptr.

Comment: Good point, but I did check those too. If I want to know if an element exists in the map I use `m_metaData.count(typeid(Class)) > 0`.

Comment: Since you haven't shown the operations you perform on the map, and you rejected the only suggestion, there's not more than can be done unless you share more information.

Comment: Well that's the thing, I know how to use a map, I know I don't perform any operation that would result in a nullptr appearing anywhere in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, in a completely different part of the code, a lambda was being called that looked like this:

```
auto cleanup = [this]() { this->m_variable = nullptr; }
```

And the `this` in question had been deleted. So it was setting some random part of the memory to a bunch of zeroes.

So to answer my own question, setting a pointer's member variable value after the pointer was deleted could cause such a problem.